# Manipulate Character array as string in c

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string

I have read that storing a string in a character array(with null termination) allows the string to be manipulated later on (unlike having a pointer to string literal).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char s[10]="Stack";
   s[9]='a'; // a gets stored in array and if index is less than 6 string gets changed
   printf("%s\n",s);    
   return 0; 
}
```

Output :  Stack

This works as long as index to be manipulated is less than length of string.

That means the string contents (and hence size) can't be changed even if there is empty space?

Is there any direct way(not using functions) to add 'a' at the position desired?

Comment: Can you explain more what is you want to do?

Comment: the short answer is "no"

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Are you aware of the fact that the 0-terminator makes all functions assume that there are no more characters in the string?

Comment: so there is no benefit of allocating an array here , the left space is lost and the string can't be manipulated

Comment: And if the OP is still around I give him this code for his amusement to show the dangers of writing into the last element of a character array: http://codepad.org/HDyACY5I

Comment: @user814064 yes that i know, printf cant stop there and if the chars are aligned contiguously in memory, result is undefined. it might have crashed even but i wanted to know how to use the left space and if its size could be changed. If one rewrites every null by whitespace to add a char at some position , and then a final whitespace , it's the only way to manipulate the string here? is it?

Comment: Right. I just wanted to show you that you can't update s[9] to 'a' and then fill the rest of the string with blanks. You need to leave some space for the null terminator, so the string needs to be at least 11.

Comment: last comment last line instead of null i wrote whitespace,silly here. So now it is fine-the way ?

Comment: @H2CO3 want to use the left-over bytes of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) will only print the characters of a string before the **NUL-terminator.**
When you set `s[9]='a';`, the contents of **s** become:

```
{'S', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', 'a'}
```

if you print `s[9]`, it's there:

```
printf("%c", s[9]);
```

Have a look at [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: yes i checked that.so a possible way would be rewrite every null to whitespace and then use the last null to print the way one wants.

Comment: "memory may become like this" is there any other way also?

Comment: use std::string if you want to append chars  to a string

Comment: thx. but please elaborate a bit on the memory representation.

Comment: @user2653718 When you initialize only part of an array or struct, like here a char array initialized with shorter string literal, then rest of allocated space is filled with 0. If you do not initialize it at all, then initial contents will be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You can always add and `'a'` at the location, but the function used to print the string needs to be different. `printf` stops printing after it encounters a `'\0'` character. You can use a function like this

```
for (i = 0; i < len_of_str; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == '\0')
         continue;
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"That means the string contents (and hence size) can't be changed even if there is empty space?" You can certainly change hte string conent (aka individual characters) but you cannot change the storage size (number of elements, in this case number of chars) in the array. Since once you define the array (in this case, s), C allocates that much storage space to it and you cannot make any assumption about the memory outside that allocated space.

"Is there any direct way(not using functions) to add 'a' at the position desired?". Yes, directly assign it. The constraint is that you should not go beyond the storage space (excluding the NUL char). For example, you could easily do "s[2]='u';" and the output would be "Stuck" instead of "Stack".

Comment: yes that is true if i have index<length only that printf is able to read it. otherwise not.

Answer (score 2):

after "stack" is set to s[10], s[0]='s', s[1]=[t]...s[4]='k', s[5]='\0'.
In C and C++, when a char array is printed as a string format, the string's length is equal to the index of'\0', regardless of how much memory is allocated for the array.

Answer (score 1):

the fast answer is "no" you can't change a size of an array of chars simply by doing

```
arr[size+1] = 'a';
```

as you can't change the size of array of integers the same way.
but you can use a dynamic string with `char *` and allocate memory to is using `malloc` function

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little bit and it's working fine.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
    char s[10]="Stack";
    s[8]='a'; // a gets stored in array and if index is less than 6 string gets changed
    s[5]='n';
    s[9]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",s);
    return 0;
 }
```

Output: stackn           //'\0' characters are not printed are not printed
First take out the null character '\0' present in s[5] position and replace with a character so that you can insert characters to the array s

Secondly, s[10] means 0-9 so replace your code s[9]='a' with s[8]='a' since to print the string you have to write null character at s[9]='\n'.

Comment: @user2653718: The answer uses C++, not C.